# how to make Kendo MultiSelect depends on another kendo dropdown within kendo grid table

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have seen the examples of kendo regarding Cascading MultiSelects but this is not within the kendo grid like below
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/multiselect/how-to/cascade/cascading-multiselects.. how about if we have a kendo grid which is having two columns like columnA ( kendo dropdown type ) and coulmnB ( kendo multiSelect type ). Now the change for row1 in columnA is affecting the datasource of row1 multiSelect columnB.
The change for row2 in columnA is affecting the datasource of row2 multiSelect columnB.

what I could do is that I have declared the model in the datasource of kendo grid like this

```
model: {
        id: "id",
        fields: 
         {
            courseName: { defaultValue: {}  ,editable: true, validation: { required: true,required: { message: "Please Select a course" }} },// this will be kendoDropDownList

            students:  { type: "string",editable: true  }// this is will be kendoMultiSelect
                }
        }// end model
```

in the grid I did like below

```
 var grid=   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    pageable: true,
                    columnMenu:true,
                    filterable:true,
                    height: 550,
                    reorderable: true,
                      columnReorder: function(e) {
                        console.log(e.column.field, e.newIndex, e.oldIndex);                                                              
                      },
                    toolbar: ["excel", { template: kendo.template($("#template").html()) } , { template: kendo.template($("#clearFilterTemplate").html()) },{template: kendo.template($("#searchTemplate").html())} ],
                    excel: {
                            fileName: "Export Table.xlsx",
                            proxyURL: "excelExport",
                            filterable: true,
                            allPages: true
                        },                        
                     editable: true,//   editable: "inline" editable: true,
                     resizable: true,
                     columns: [
                                 { field: "checkbox", title: "Box", width: 50,  template: "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox' class='checkbox' />"  },  

                                  {
                                          field: "courseName",editor: courseEditor,title:"Course", width: 200

                                },
                                {
                                          field: "students",editor: studentsEditor,title:"Students", width: 200

                                }

                               // { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }

                            ]


                });

 function courseEditor(container, options)
 {
  var selectedRowModel = options.model;


                                    var input = $('<input id="courseName" name="courseName">'); 

                                    // append to the editor container
                                    input.appendTo(container);

                                    // initialize a dropdownlist
                                    input.kendoDropDownList({
                                        dataTextField: "text",
                                        dataValueField: "value", 

                                       change: function (e) { },

                                        dataSource: {
                                        dataType: "json",                                 
                                        transport: {
                                            read: "getCourses"

                                                  }// end transport
                                           }// datasource
                                    }).appendTo(container);                                 

 }

 function studentsEditor(container, options)
 {

  $("<select multiple='multiple' data-bind='value :students'/>")
      .appendTo(container)
      .kendoMultiSelect({
      valuePrimitive: true,
      dataSource: studentInitialDataSource,
      dataTextField: "text",
      dataValueField: "value",
      //cascadeFrom: "courseName", // cascade from courseName dropdownlist
       change: function (e) { },
      open: function(e) {
            //var item = e.item;
            //var text = item.text();
            // Use the selected item or its text

             var selectedRowModel = options.model;
             var courseName= selectedRowModel.courseName;
             if( courseName== null )
             {
                alert("yes it is null the courseName");

             }
             else
             {
                alert("no it is not null see courseName:"+courseName);

                var newDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "getStudents?courseName="+courseName,
                            dataType: "json"
                            /*data: {
                                q: function() {
                                    return $("#searchFor").val();
                                              }
                                    }*/
                        }
                    }
                });

                this.setDataSource(newDataSource );  
                //shecdulCycleDataSource = secondDataSource   ;

             }

          }
    });


 }
```

if you see above I have used this.setDataSource(newDataSource ); to change the datasource of kendoMultipleSelect when it is opening , but what I need when the course value is changing the student list also change automatically

how to do that , any example it will be appreciated

Comment: if possible could you please share what have you tried?

Comment: Jayesh Goyani , thank you for the reply , I have updated what I have done and tried , can you please advice me how to do that?.

Comment: Jayesh Goyani , no solution for this ...